# Is there a way to implement Wikipedia page preview in markdown files?

Tags: wikipedia

I am writting markdown file and I would like to link some of the words in my markdown to small Wikipedia-like page preview. Is there a way to implement it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The feature is called [Page Previews](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Page_Previews) (previously, it was called Hovercards). There is no official support for using it outside of Wikipedia, but there is a third-party library, [AnandChowdhary/hovercard](https://github.com/AnandChowdhary/hovercard). Also [a bunch of browser plugins](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Seq3z026jcarkaji).